# Calculating rolling sum based on dates being in a range of calendar dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, rolling-computation

I want to calculate rolling sum based not on ordered date rows but on the condition of dates being in range of calendar dates:

[image]

Basically I want to be able to `sum values` in **qty** column `where date range varies from current date minus 4 calendar days`. For example:

[image]

As it can be seen from the picture, I calculate rolling sum but it is based on 4 calendar days back from the current date. And The red arrow shows the case with 16th of February when 4 calendar days must include all Qty-s to 12th of February. In this table I have only 3 records between 16th and 12th of February.

This condition does not allow me to use OVER clause since I have no idea how many rows from my table will be included in the range (which is not 4 days, I gave it here as an example and it may vary).
I would appreciate suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

`APPLY` is probably the simplest solution:

```
select t.*, t2.*
from t outer apply
     (select sum(t2.qty) as qty_4
      from t t2
      where t2.date <= t.date and
            t2.date >= dateadd(day, -4, t.date)
     ) t2;
```

Comment: Written this way it returns duplications. Date is repeating multiple times as well as qty_4. I tried `GROUP BY` but then I don't get result. And it forces me to group by all columns.

Comment: Can you please edit your question or give another possible solution?

Comment: @Yana . . . This returns *exactly* the rows in `t`.  There are only duplicates if that table has duplicates.  If that is an issue, ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: I don't have duplicates in my table. But I have Ids. So i write `sum(t2.qty) over(partition by id)`

Comment: @Yana . . . This answer should do what you want and there are no window function.  Your question has no ids, so that is not relevant to the answer, but presumably you want to add `t2.id = t.id`.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @table table (QTY int, [Date] datetime)
insert into @table values (1,'2/23/2021')
insert into @table values(2,'2/20/2021')
insert into @table values(3,'2/19/2021')
insert into @table values(4,'2/17/2021')
insert into @table values(5,'2/16/2021')
insert into @table values(6,'2/15/2021')
insert into @table values(7,'2/14/2021')
insert into @table values(8,'2/5/2021')
insert into @table values(9,'1/30/2021')
insert into @table values(10,'1/29/2021')
insert into @table values(11,'1/24/2021')

select t.*,( 
select sum(t2.qty) 
  from @table t2
  where t2.date <= t.date 
  and   t2.date >= dateadd(day, -4, t.date)) as SUM_QTY
FROM
@table t
```